# כֻּלָּם אֲהוּבִים - further reading please

Tags: sources-mekorot, tefilla, hashkafah-philosophy, malach-angel, love

Every day in the berachot of Shema, we describe the angels who praise Hashem as כֻּלָּם אֲהוּבִים, all beloved. I would like further reading on this description of them. Anything: who they are, why they are beloved, how an angel without free will can be beloved, what is loveable about them, why we need to know they are beloved. As I said, any sources that discuss this point are most welcome, thank you

Comment: See Ohr HaTorah on the siddur. For particulars, see מלאכים in the index.

Comment: It is worth noting that based on Esther 2:2, that these "personal servants" are also called "Youths", in the same way that Chanoch ben Yered is also called "the Youth" after ascending to Heaven alive (he does not experience death). And in the same way see Ibn Ezra to Bereshit 28:12:1 and Moreh Nevuchim, Part 2:32:6.  https://www.sefaria.org/Guide_for_the_Perplexed%2C_Part_2.32.6?vhe=Moreh_Nevuchim,_translated_by_Ibn_Tibon&lang=bi

Comment: Seems to me that before trying to figure out why x-entity is beloved by God, you'd need to first identify what it means to be beloved by God.

Comment: @Deuteronomy indeed that would be a high quality answer. Or a link to another question asking that, if it exists. Perhaps it should if not

Comment: Another point to consider: כולם אהובים is often conventionally translated as referring to the malakhim as being beloved by God... but is it possible to read it otherwise (i.e. that they are beloved by each other? by the rest of creation?)

Comment: @Deuteronomy very good point. See what Rabbeinu Tam says here: https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_HaYashar.5.8, what do you make of it?